# Как перевести "Storage was removed or unmounted"

Tags: переводы

Требуется перевести на нормальный русский язык выражение:

```
Storage was removed or unmounted
```

**Контекст**: речь идет о переводе сообщения для программы на смартфон, когда вытаскивается карта памяти или USB устройство - необходимо выкинуть сообщение юзеру.

**Уточнение:** перевод должен быть для домохозяек, то есть перевод типа:

```
Том с данными удален или демонтирован
```

не принимается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(если о физическом отключении названных устройств памяти)

Накопитель вынут или отсоединён.

Comment: Alex_ander, ну вы же опытный пользователь, отвечайте суть подробнее, чтобы потом у проверяющего голова не болела гадать, что вы изволили сказать.

Comment: А так, если разобраться, то да.  Перевод вполне приемлемый.

Comment: Это не для домохозяек, точно.

Comment: Unmount, к сожалению, не подразумевает отсоединения, тут суть как раз в том, что карта может оставаться присоединённой, но для того, чтоб с ней работать, необходимо произвести remount, прежде чем к ней обращаться. Буквальный перевод - седлать, но тут конечно он неуместен. А так по смыслу то же самое, - если спешился, то, даже если конь у тебя всё ещё на поводу, всё равно для того, чтобы на нём снова куда-нибудь скакать, надо его сперва заново оседлать.